# Detect repeated characters in Arabic tokens

Tags: java, arabic

Kindly, I need your help in the following:

How I can detect repeated characters in tokens, for example:

If I have this sentence:
كييييف نستطيع التوااصل مع الطلاب؟

I want a java code that detect each word that contains repeated characters then remove them (the repeated characters) and update the word.

So, our sentence should be:
كيف نستطيع التواصل مع الطلاب؟

Notice the word "كييييف" as contains repeated character "ي", it should be updated to be only "كيف" and "التوااصل"  became "التواصل".

I approciate your help.

Comment: You can use unicode for that particular arabic character.

Comment: note that you need to check the existence of the word before and after deleting the repeated characters, for instance the word: كييف is the name of "Kiev" (capital of Ukraine) in Arabic

Comment: you can compare them using the charAt() method.

Comment: @Sunny could you please clarify more?

Comment: @elsadek thank you for this remark; you meant to ensure that not to lose the word, right?

Comment: @yitzih thank you it seems that it is the only option, but I was searching a more effective way.

Comment: @Eng.Lolina indeed, unless it doesn't matter in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lolina, loops are not of much help. Did you hear about regular expressions. Java uses them as many other languages such as Perl and Python. I am familiar with Python but regex almost have similar functions in all languages.

What you need now is to read about regular expressions in Java and especially read about the metacharacters * and + which match 0 or more and 1 or more characters respectively.

First try to compile simple regular expressions and then add extra stuff to them so that they perform what you actually want to do.

Finally, regular expressions are a bit confusing at the beginning but they worth the trouble. Remeber that Stanford Arabic POS tagger uses  regular expressions to perform things similar to what you are trying to do.

I am not familiar at all with Java, but in Python, I would do it as follows:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('ي+') # The + sign means match at least more than one occurrence of ي 
>>> p.sub('ي', 'كييييييييف نتواصل مع الطلاب')
'كيف نتواصل مع الطلاب'
```

Usually in Arabic we repeat typing the following three letters, ا, ي, and و. These are the vowels of Arabic. You can compile a regex for ي and strip them off. Then compile another one for ا and one more for و.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Yes, sue I heard about them, but my knowledge is limited in using hem, so kindly could you suggest the regex what it will be?

Comment: Lolina, I have updated my answer with an example in Python. I hope it will help you!

Comment: thank you it works! But I am wondering how I can generalize it for all Arabic letters?

Answer (score 1):

One option (please consider my knowledge of Arabic is non-existant) is to split the string by space delimiters and then check each of the split strings for the character repeats using the charAt method or using indexOf using the unicode character values of the particular characters you wish to check for.

Comment: Do you mean that for each word, I will compare each character with the character before it then if they are the same delete one of them?

Comment: thank you it seems that it is the only option, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, you can compare each word, such that you find a character, find if it's repeated, then delete the repeats using this method.  Imagine using two loops, the outer loop can check for each character in a word, then the inner loop can check if that character is repeated.  Then you can form new strings without those characters in order to remove the occurrences of the repeated characters.